# Корректность работы команды ping (windows) при низких значениях таймаута -w

Tags: ping

В консоли (Win7x64) даю команду *ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1 -w 10* и получаю ответ
**Ответ от 8.8.8.8: число байт=32 время=37мс TTL=48**
Почему утилита ждала целых 37мс ответ от "8.8.8.8", если я задал таймаут в 10мс?
P.S. данная ситуация воспроизвелась на разных версиях Windows и при пинге разных хостов. Для исключения ДНС-траблов имена узлов указывались в виде ип-адреса.

Comment: Не уверен, как там в Windows, но вроде бы, вы задали таймаут 10 секунд.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov, нет, для Windows это точно миллисекунды. Вот фрагмент справки _ping /?_    _ -w <тайм-аут>         Тайм-аут для каждого ответа (в миллисекундах).__

Comment: Я немного поэкспериментировал ... походу она не способна отсчитать задержки с точностью менее 500 ms (+-). А почему, боюсь, не видя ее исходников сказать это невозможно.

Comment: @Mike, у меня примерно те же результаты. Насколько смог понять - корни уходят в icmp.dll. Выходит, что в древней утилите, живущей в ОС много лет - по сей день есть баг? Интересно с чем связан и как обойти? Кроме того, когда пингую **ping 8.8.8.7 -n 10 -w 100** то итог будет через ~14с вместо 1--1,5с - И это проблема при опросе около 50 хостов, из которых ночью работают 1-2....